# nginx proxy_pass on same domain results in 502 / 499

Tags: nginx, debian, webserver, nginx-reverse-proxy

My goal is, to include on `https://my-host.de/sub/include-to-show/` a page from a cms and manipulate it later via the subs_filter.
So i did a new location and made a proxy_pass to the page that i want to show and manipulate.
With the following config i get a status 502 on `https://my-host.de/sub/include-to-show/` and a status 499 from `https://my-host.de/sub/source-page` - sadly no further logs

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name my-host.de;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;
    include snippets/ssl-parameters.conf;

    root /var/www/my-host/htdocs;
    index index.php;

    access_log /var/www/my-host/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/my-host/logs/error.log;

    client_max_body_size 512M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ /(.+\.php)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm-default.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            include fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

            include /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }

    location /sub/include-to-show/ {
        proxy_pass https://my-host.de/sub/source-page;
        proxy_redirect default;
    }
}
```

If i change the Domain from the proxy_pass to another one it works.
What am i doing wrong?

Already tried this settings in the proxy_pass location part:

```
proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Edit: By the way - the Setup worked 2 weeks ago. Currently on debian stretch

Comment: Is `https://my-host.de/sub/source-page` hosted on the same server? And if directly accessing that URL fails, why would a reverse proxy do any better?

Comment: it is on the same server and in the same config (see snippet). Accessing the URL directly does work, also with curl on the same machine.

Comment: Why reverse: I have to filter & replace some elements with sub_filters

Comment: Maybe i was wrote a little bit confused. The 499 just got thrown via reverse_proxy, if i access it directly it works with a 200

Comment: I understand, so the access log shows a 502 for the original request and a 499 for the proxy passed request. Is there anything in the error log?

Comment: correct @RichardSmith - sadly nothing in the error.log

Comment: seems to be a issue with ssl renegotiation on the same server. turning hsts off and calling the port 80 works.